# Replace a character from a returned string of variable

Tags: python, string, file, variables, replace

I'm trying to replace a character of a returned string. 
First I get the string with

```
import os
import re

#List .xlsx files followed by the string ESC
filenames = os.listdir('//xxx.xxx.xxx.com//a//b//c//archive')
for filename in filenames:
    getdate = re.search('(?<=ESC_)\w+', filename)
    print (getdate)
```

In return I get this

```
<re.Match object; span=(27, 34), match='2020_01'>
None
```

Which is correct.
I subsequently try this:

```
#Replace '_' with '-'
date = getdate.replace('_', '-')
print(date)
```

But it gives me an error

```
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'replace'
```

Any advice? Is the string which is returned from (getdate) not recognized?

Also how do I write that string to a .prm file with some extra values, like:

```
Body of .prm file has (date), aaaa, bbbb and cccc
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the output you included shows that the first filename matches, but the second one doesn't. If we look at the [documentation for search](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.search), we see that it will return a `Match` object if there was a match, or `None` if there wasn't one.

[None](https://docs.python.org/3/library/constants.html?highlight=none#None) is a special value in python (like NULL) in other languages, that represents "nothing". It simply doesn't have a `replace` method! That's exactly what the error says.

So you need to check first, whether you even got a result in the first place:

```
if getdate:
  date = getdate.group(0).replace('_', '-')
```

So check if you have "something" (as opposed to "None"), than do your operation on something. You can also find this pattern in the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#match-objects).

Note that `search` does **not** return a string. It returns a `Match` Object (or None). Your regex can use groups to capture multiple things, but in this case you only have one, which is in group 0. That gets you the actual string.